# White background visible in UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, swift2

I have added a `UISegmentedControl` from storyboard and from code I am editing it like this from controller

```
segmentedCntrl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
segmentedCntrl.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
segmentedCntrl.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
segmentedCntrl.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

and in `appdelegate`

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 17.0/255.0, green: 150.0/255.0, blue: 182.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
UISegmentedControl.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintAdjustmentMode = .Normal
```

but I get this as output

[image]
Little white line is visible at last of segmented control.

From storyboard I haven't made much changes that can cause this.
[image]

I am on Swift 2.3 and Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: Check run time view hierarchy, what actually present there. For details, print description of that component.

Comment: I have done that already but did not see anything suspicious.